# Best way to store an AES-encrypted byte and IV to an XML?

Tags: xml, linq, c#-4.0, encoding, cryptography

I am new to both encoding and cryptography, so the question I ask may be too basic. I have a requirement to encrypt a value that is provided to me and store the encrypted value as well as the IV used for encryption in a document. The encryption is done using a master key that is stored elsewhere. I use AES encryption and the code for encryption looks like this:

```
 private EncryptedData EncryptValue(string value, byte[] encryptedMasterKey)
        {
            byte[] encryptedValue = new byte[0];
            AesCryptoServiceProvider aesCryptoServiceProvider = null;

            //decrypt the master key
            encryptedMasterKey = DecryptMasterKey(encryptedMasterKey);

            // Create an AesCryptoServiceProvider object
            // with the specified key and IV.                   
            using (aesCryptoServiceProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aesCryptoServiceProvider.Key = encryptedMasterKey;

                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesCryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor(
                    aesCryptoServiceProvider.Key, aesCryptoServiceProvider.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(value);
                        }
                        encryptedValue = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            EncryptedData encryptedData = new EncryptedData(encryptedValue, aesCryptoServiceProvider.IV);
            return encryptedData;
        }
```

The code to write the data to the XML looks like this:

```
public void WriteData(string id, EncryptedData encryptedData)
    {

        XDocument document = GetValidDocument();
        XElement[] encryptedDataElements = null;
        XElement encryptedDataElement;
        encryptedDataElements = (from element in document.Descendants(EncryptedDataElementName)
                                 where element.Element(IdElementName).Value.ToUpper() == id.ToUpper()
                                 select element).ToArray();
        if (encryptedDataElements.Count() != 0)
        {
            encryptedDataElement = encryptedDataElements.First();
            encryptedDataElement.Remove();
        }
        encryptedDataElement = new XElement(EncryptedDataElementName);
        XElement idElement = new XElement(IdElementName, id);
        encryptedDataElement.Add(idElement);
        XElement encryptedValueElement = new XElement(EncryptedValueElementName);
        encryptedValueElement.SetValue(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedData.EncryptedValue));
        XElement saltElement = new XElement(SaltElementName, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedData.Salt));
        encryptedDataElement.Add(encryptedValueElement);
        encryptedDataElement.Add(saltElement);
        document.Element(StoreElementName).Add(encryptedDataElement);
        IXmlService xmlService = GlueRegistry.Instance.GetService<IXmlService>();
        xmlService.SaveXmlDocument(document, filePath);
    }
```

I figured that it is probably better to save as a UTF8 encoded string and get the values back as UTF8 encoded byte arrays. Serialization is not an option as data is written one by one. The problem is in the SetValue methods with the Encoding.UTF8.GetString. I also understand that I should probably use XElement.Parse. I used that and I get an exception saying that the value is invalid. I am now wondering whether UTF8 is a good choice, or if there is another better way to do what I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For encoding I recommend Base64. Utf8 is designed to transform text to bytes. It cannot transform arbitrary binary data to text.
2. I recommend using authenticated encryption/adding a MAC. Unauthenticated encryption invites active attacks, such as padding oracles.

So your code becomes something like:

```
byte[] ciphertext = iv + Encrypt(key, m);
byte[] ciphertextWithMAC = ciphertext + HMAC(key, ciphertext)
string encodedCiphertext = Base64Encode(cipherText)
```

Comment: I so much agree with using authenticated encryption. Many attacks are possible without it.

Answer (score 0):

While I have some doubts, whether it is a good idea to store the encryption of a single byte,
which begs for brute force attacks, the form of representation is obvious for me: Use the data type hexBinary (so "ABC" will be something like "414243"). This doubles the length of the encryption value, but due to the XML overhead this is unlikely to matter. Advantages are: no special character handling needed, clearly visible and somewhat readable.

Comment: There is no reason why a a single encrypted byte would be more vulnerable to attack than multiple.

Comment: @CodesinChaos: Just 256 different inputs to try looks like more vulnerable for me?!

Comment: @guidot How would you know which input is right? In general, having more plaintext/ciphertext is detrimental to security as there is more to test. That still does not matter much if your protocol is well designed of course.